# Moment of inertia of a cone frustum with a cylinder cut out (using integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, applications

How can I find moment of inertia of this frustum when the mass **M** is uniformly distributed through the grey region using integration?

The hints said to break the region into two pieces, one with cylindrical shell with distance from axis is between 5 & 6, and other is the sloping region with distance from axis is between 6 & 10.

I'm finding it difficult to solve this from these hints.
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to compute M.I. for a cylinder? What did you get? But this type of questions are closed early on in this site... unless you show your work and effort made so far.

Comment: I can compute M.I. of cylinder. I get 1/2MR^2 when it is rotating about central axis.

Comment: Can you compute the solid frustum without the given hint?

Comment: I know the moment of inertia of solid frustum only. But can't really derive that one.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia (MI) of a **solid** frustrum can be obtained by subtracting that of a smaller solid cone from that of a larger cone. The dimensions of the 2 cones can be calculated by proportions from the dimensions of the frustrum.

The MI of a **hollow** frustrum can be obtained by subtracting that of a solid cylinder from that of the frustrum.

Alternatively the MI of the frustrum can be obtained by integration of a series of thin washers with constant inner radius and variable outer radius.

Comment: I'm having problem with different masses of each cone and cylinder

Comment: @SajibIglesias Try writing the mass as volume x density. Density is the same for all cones and cylinder.

Comment: The only saviour "density". Thanks a lot @sammygerbil